# Cassandra not value inserted

Tags: cassandra-0.7

I'm using cassandra.my columnfamily is testcassa and the column is test1. I tried to insert value like **set testcassa['123'][test1]='Sample'** but it returns 'null'. and no error message.. can anyone help me..

thanks in advance.

Comment: 1.remove the dead nodes which are all ring in the cluster 2.restart cassandra server. Then it will insert

Comment: You should probably paste your entire session. It's not even clear if you're using the cli or some other interface.

Answer (score 0):

```
[default@unknown] create keyspace mykeyspace;
[default@unknown] use mykeyspace;
[default@mykeyspace] set cf1[1]['c2']=utf8('test');
[default@mykeyspace] get cf1[1];
[default@mykeyspace] set cf1[1]['c2']=utf8('test2');
[default@mykeyspace] del cf1[1];
```